# Show price with discount in the "add to cart confirmation" popup in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: views, rules, commerce

I'm using the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution for a e-commerce site.

I create a rule to apply a price discount to a product which is fired when the buyer enters a code.

The discount works fine, but when I add the product to the cart a popup shows up to notify you that the product has been added to the cart (and give you the option to continue shopping or go to the cart). In this popup, created with a view the module defines, the price for the product is shown without the discount.

I need to show the price with the applied discount. How can I do this?

I also need to show a message inside this popup, something like "You get the discount!" I already added a second action to the rule to show this message, but I don't know how to show it inside the popup.

How can I show a system message inside a view?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should spend some more time on your question - how is the popup created - what does it display.

Comment: Please provide more details about the view. Knowing the settings for that view would also help. I am going to close this question, but the status of closed is not permanent. If the question provides more information that allows users to answer, it can be re-opened.

Comment: I understand the reason of why this question is closed. But I don't agree with "an extraordinarily narrow situation" since a price discount is a very usual practice when selling products. This popup is a default feature provided by the commerce kickstart (version 2) distribution and knowing how to add or remove information in it would very useful for others to know.

Comment: Too localize is the closing reason that is also used for something that cannot be reproduced from other users. The assumption was that you were talking of a view you created. As the view is a default view defined from the module, that doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: @googletorp: I didn't create the view. It is provided by the distribution. This popup is new feature of the distribution (version 2)

Comment: I think this issue is no longer present in Kickstart RC3 and newer.
We previously showed only the product base price in the popup, but now the line item total price is shown instead.